# The series $1-1+1-1+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

$1+x+x^2+\dots=\frac{1}{1-x}$, where $-1<x<1$

But I saw in one video this expression is true for $x=-1$ too. So can I write $1+x+x^2+\dots=\frac{1}{1-x}$, where $-1\le x<1$?

Comment: Forget that. Numberphile itself has a way better [video](https://youtu.be/0Oazb7IWzbA).

Comment: which video, can you give the link please! And also as Oliva said, that Numberphile video is very good... take a look at it.

Comment: thanks for the link sir @J.M.isn'tamathematician

Comment: @user467365: Numberphile is full of nonsense that is **not** mathematics at all! Worse still, its mathematically unsound rubbish gives mathematics a bad name because laymen who **don't know better** think that it is a good representative of mathematicians. That's just false.

Comment: but @user21820 most of numberphile vids are made by university mathematician (although they do not explain topics at all). Btw my favourite  is **3Blue1Brown**.

Comment: @user467365: You're wrong. Most of those videos are made by an amateur who has no rigorous mathematical training.

Comment: @user21820 the vids I saw, that guy just ask question... and one prof explains it. What you said in your first comment is 100% right,

Comment: @user467365: I'm not surprised if there are a couple of videos that are based on interviews of actual professors. However, note that even then there may have been video editing done. The main problem is that the vast majority of those videos are not mathematically rigorous and often dreadfully wrong. Yet it's the most popular layman math video channel online...

Answer (score 3):

No. The geometric seies $1+x+x^2+\dots$ coverges $ \iff -1 <x <1$. In this case we have

$1+x+x^2+\dots=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

For $x=-1$ the series is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

What we mean by $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ is the limit of the partial sums $a_n=\sum_{r=0}^n x^r$. When $-1<x<1$ then it is possible to show that this limit exists and equals $\frac 1{1-x}$. But when $x=-1$ we ahve $a_n=1$ if $n$ is even, and $a_n=0$ if $n$ is odd, so they don't tend to a limit.